# Charset with Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, character-encoding

I needed to work with Facebook SDK, so with some help, I wrote script that can find informations about person. But if there is diacritic in his/her name, it will be malformed, I tried to set charset in SDK files, but it doesn't help.

For example, if the name is René Beneš, it will be RenĂ© BeneĹˇ.

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can describe, at the character level, what is going on here – I hope it helps you closer to a solution. You apparently get the data in UTF-8 encoding, but your software interprets it as ISO-8859-2 (ISO Latin 2, “East European”) encoding. For example, letter “é” (U+00E9) is two bytes 0xC3 0xA9 in UTF-8. If the bytes are incorrectly interpreted according to ISO-8859-2, 0xC3 becomes Ă and 0xA9 becomes ©.

So you should try to make your software read and process the data in UTF-8 or to transcode it from UTF-8 to the encoding you use.

Comment: yeah, ive found problem, like you said I have gotdata in UTF-8 but in my page, there was windows-1250 encoding, when I tried to change it to utf-8, everything was OK. Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure utf8_decode and/or utf8_encode will work great for you.

Answer (score -2):

***1st Example - PHP***

I suggest you to use PHP function called str_replace():

```
$name = 'RenĂ© BeneĹˇ';

$replace = array('Ă©','Ĺˇ');
$replaced = array('e','s');

// output = Rene Benes
echo str_replace($replace, $replaced, $name);
```

You can find more about that function on [official PHP website - str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Furthermore, more informations and HTML codes about special characters are available on [Special Characters in HTML](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

***2nd Example - HTML***

Try to replace:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

between your `<head></head>` section.

Comment: Yeah, I know about this function, but I know that there is some way how to do it without it, because lot of pages, including this one have the diacritic.