# Posting UK Sterling (£) symbol in status updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I'm trying to post "£" to a page in a status update via the Graph API but every attempt has failed.

Here's what I see in the post when I try different attempts:

```
£ -> Sqaure symbol in IE, or black diamond with "?" in the centre in other browsers
&pound; -> &pound;
&#163; -> &#163;
%A3 -> %A3
```

Does anyone know what else I can use to get the "£" symbol?

EDIT: I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was a problem with the FTP transfer. When I looked at the file locally, I saw the £ sign. After pushing it via FTP, I looked at the remote file and where "£" should have been, it was replaced with "?".

In the end I created a new file, copied and pasted the code into the new file, pushed it to the server and tried again. Now it works. Weird?!

Answer (score 0):

I've used \u and then a four figue hex code before. It works (I think) when it's going through javascript

\u00a3

Comment: Sorry. Worth a go, I suppose. I don't know nuffink about the FB SDK.

Comment: Have you made sure that your page is encoded in UTF-8? Here's a link that mentions a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149916/charset-with-facebook-sdk